# Why does KMeans' silhouette_score change after restarting runtime in Google Colab?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, google-colaboratory, k-means

I'm trying to get reproducible results from sklearn's KMeans running on a Google Colab notebook.
The Kmeans algorithm is being fit on an array generated by a Principal Component Analysis (PCA).
Every time I restart the notebook's runtime, fit, predict and generate the silhouette_score of a K-means algorithm, the silhouette_score changes!

Here's the code that I run to fit and predict using Kmeans and to generate the silhouette_score:

```
for n_clusters in range(3,9):
    kmeans = KMeans(init= 'k-means++', n_clusters = n_clusters, n_init= 25, random_state = 0)
    kmeans.fit(pca_mat_products)
    clusters = kmeans.predict(pca_mat_products)
    silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(mp_matrix, clusters, random_state= 0)
    print("For n_clusters =", n_clusters, "The average silhouette_score is :", silhouette_avg)
```

Here's an example of the silhouette_scores generated:

```
For n_clusters = 3 The average silhouette_score is : 0.08689747798228342
For n_clusters = 4 The average silhouette_score is : 0.11513524544540599
For n_clusters = 5 The average silhouette_score is : 0.13225896257848024
For n_clusters = 6 The average silhouette_score is : 0.13390795741576195
For n_clusters = 7 The average silhouette_score is : 0.11262045164741093
For n_clusters = 8 The average silhouette_score is : 0.12179451798486395
```

When I restart the notebook's runtime while maintaining everything the same on the notebook (including *random_state =0*), and run the cells from scratch, new silhouette_scores appear each time I restart the notebook.

Here's the silhouette_scores generated by the same code in a different run:

```
For n_clusters = 3 The average silhouette_score is : 0.09181951382862036
For n_clusters = 4 The average silhouette_score is : 0.11539863985647045
For n_clusters = 5 The average silhouette_score is : 0.13363229313208771
For n_clusters = 6 The average silhouette_score is : 0.13428788881085452
For n_clusters = 7 The average silhouette_score is : 0.13187306014661757
For n_clusters = 8 The average silhouette_score is : 0.13252806332855294
```

In further runtimes the silhouette_scores keep changing.

*mp_matrix* is a one-hot encoded array, looking as follows:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]])
```

Is it normal for the silhouette_scores to changes after restarting runtime in Google Colab?
Is there any way to obtain reproducible silhouette_scores?

I've searched here and in other places online and didn't find this issue being discussed.

Thank you!

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: what is the value of `init`?

Comment: init is currently = 'k-means++', I've added it to the code.

Comment: what is `mp_matrix` here?

Comment: mp_matrix is a one-hot encoded array. I've added how it looks like to the question.

Comment: Are you sure your other data is not changing? On this website (and elsewhere), when asking for help, it is really important to try to provide an [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example) so others can try to replicate your problem. Sometimes, while isolating the problem to produce the MWE, you may even find the bug and end up not needing help any more.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your issue in Colab with a dataset created using `make_blobs()` and another fake dataset to use where you use the `mp_matrix` data. I get the same average silhouette scores after restarting runtime.  Consider the answer from @dpkandy.  There is no randomness in computing silhouette scores unless you are using samples/subsets of data.

Comment: @LucaCiti, I totally agree with you. Since the dataset is large I didn't know how to insert it here. Would sharing the original notebook help? (https://colab.research.google.com/drive/17hpVXXymWwCFlKszZGWEHPKakQw0aNfW?usp=sharing)

Comment: @AlexK, you're right, the answer from dpkandy solved the issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your code it seems like you are doing your clustering based on the result of a PCA:

```py
  kmeans.fit(pca_mat_products)
  clusters = kmeans.predict(pca_mat_products)
```

If you need reproducible results for the PCA, set the random_state there too.

Here the doc: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html

Comment: Exactly, the cause was the randomness in the results of the PCA that is generating the results used for clustering. I set the random_state in the PCA as well and it solved the issue. Thank you very much!